# Literary phrasing (gold-pressed)

Tags: figures-of-speech, lyrics

> Gold pressed temptress of silence
>
> Let the morning call unanswered
>
> And ransom the day off

**Song**: *Good Love*, by Zola Blood

What exactly is *gold pressed*? A fictional reference or some metalsmith terminology?

About "temptress of silence", does it mean she seduces by leaving unspoken? The other way around, like she lures *sb* into being quiet?

Comment: It might be a variation on "gilt" , which is more common. Gilding is often done by pressing gold leaf onto a surface, and often indicates high value or status. I don't think "gold pressed" is a common expression although it comes up in Star Trek.

Comment: Indeed, when I googled it, references of Star Trek (related to this word "latinum") were the main results. I don't know the plot, is it an ingot of gold?

Comment: *Gold-pressed* seems to be a reference to a coin or money, given the appearance of *ransom*.

Comment: Gold pressing is an embossing technique used in jewelry making to clad a thin gold sheet onto another metal. I don't have a ready reference so I can't write an answer. If I recall *doublée* is related; it might be a specific technique

Comment: So is it correct to say it's the same as gold plating? I speak Portuguese, and here we call this something like ~gold-leafed~ literally.

Comment: @Peter In Star Trek, gold-pressed latinum is the fictional currency used by an alien species (called Ferengi) that worships trade. I also haven't ever heard the term outside that context.

Comment: @Peter not exactly the same as gold plating although the result (a thin layer of gold on the surface) is the same. Gold *pressing* presses gold foil on the surface using mechanical force; gold *plating* deposits gold in solution using electrochemistry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to this question, I don't think I've ever heard "gold-pressed" used outside of Star Trek. In Star Trek, gold-pressed latinum is the currency used by an alien species (called Ferengi) that worships trade (they're an allusion to the stereotypes of Jews in many Earth cultures).

Latinum itself is a liquid at room temperature, so it's difficult to handle by itself. So it's infused into bars of gold so it can be carried around. "Pressed" refers to the fact that the bars have markings pressed into them. See [here](https://qr.ae/pvLMAX) for the explanation and a picture of the markings.

This takes place in a future society where most materials can be replicated cheaply, so gold is no longer valuable for its scarcity. But latinum can't be replicated, so it has become the valuable commodity, and gold is just the wrapper.

However, it's not clear that the term is being used the same way in the poem.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! Now I'm almost sure the lyrics allude to this. It's as though he's referring to gold itself as the temptress and the silence as the valuable substance she hides within. Hence the advice to pay the morning call with silence, in order to purchase the day-off, supposedly "kidnapped" and then allowed freedom.